# flutter cropping around Card with getOuterPath and ShapeBorder

Tags: flutter

In `flutter` i'm trying to cropping around `Cart`, this action can be done easily? i can't find any documentation or hacking ideas

[image]

when we create this widget with `CustomPainter` we can't set shadow, is any body can help us to solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: why do you think you need a `CustomPainter`? what you need is `ShapeDecoration` /  `ShapeBorder` (btw even when using `CustomPainter` you can setup your `Paint` object with `MaskFilter`)

Comment: so what kind of problem do you have with custom `ShapeBorder`?

Comment: @pskink i can't use that

Comment: what is unclear then? you have a `Card`, right? and you dont know how to shape it?

Comment: @pskink yes, thats right, i can't find out any sample code or tutorial about that

Comment: as i said use custom `ShapeBorder`class  - it can be used as [Card.shape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/shape.html) property

Comment: @pskink do you have any sample code?

Comment: no, I don't, but what you need is to return your `Path` from `getOuterPath` method

Comment: @pskink https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541455/1830228

Comment: so it wasnt that hard, was it?

Comment: @pskink yes that was hard for me, i khow how can i doing that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be like that:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Card(
              shape: DurmaShape(
                borderRadius: Radius.circular(20),
                holeSize: 40,
                offset: Offset(30, -30),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
              elevation: 7,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 280,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DurmaShape extends ShapeBorder {
  DurmaShape({
    @required this.borderRadius,
    @required this.holeSize,
    this.offset = Offset.zero,
    this.side = BorderSide.none,
  });

  final Radius borderRadius;
  final Offset offset;
  final BorderSide side;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    if (side != BorderSide.none) {
      canvas.drawPath(
        _getPath(rect),
        side.toPaint(),
      );
    }
  }

  Path _getPath(Rect rect) {
    return Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()
        ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, borderRadius))
        ..close(),
      Path()
        ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
          center: Offset(0, rect.height) + offset,
          radius: holeSize,
        ))
        ..close(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  final double holeSize;

  @override
  ui.Path getOuterPath(ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) =>
      _getPath(rect);

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi dude, how can i set border for this Card? for example: `decoration: BoxDecoration(
border: Border.all(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),width: 1.0)),` you can this screen shot as sample: https://imgur.com/a/aujwaIV